# Getting 200 in response but not data is getting returned in react app, where as hitting url directly on browser getting response

Tags: java, reactjs, spring, nginx, spring-security

i have configured nginx proxy server so that both backend server and fron-end server are in same domain now to avoid CORS error but not able to get response in my react app though status returns 200 and i also could see no errors in backend server and even sql are getting executed when calling api from front end but not getting any response but if i hit same api directly from browser able to get data. below is the code.

Security config.java

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
    httpSecurity.csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/signup","/login","/getAuthors","/getPostsByViews","/api/**","/getPosts","/viewPost/**").permitAll().
            anyRequest().authenticated().and().
            exceptionHandling().and().sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    httpSecurity.addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
}
```

response in react app
[image]

if i hit same api from browser able to get results

Request Headers:

```
General:
Request URL: http://localhost/api/getPostsByViews
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 200 
Remote Address: 127.0.0.1:80
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade

Response Headers:
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Sun, 21 Jun 2020 14:03:32 GMT
Expires: 0
Pragma: no-cache
Server: nginx/1.17.7
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Vary: Origin
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Method
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Headers
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block

Request Headers:
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-IN,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Connection: keep-alive
Content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Cookie: _ga=GA1.1.293989085.1578055123; mp_999298550de6b51ad4a2d300f953b8d5_mixpanel=%7B%22distinct_id%22%3A%20%22app_EMP_MAIN_1%22%2C%22%24device_id%22%3A%20%2216f6b6a3d52578-037bb41e3a8c5a-1d376b5b-fa000-16f6b6a3d538df%22%2C%22%24initial_referrer%22%3A%20%22%24direct%22%2C%22%24initial_referring_domain%22%3A%20%22%24direct%22%2C%22%24user_id%22%3A%20%22app_EMP_MAIN_1%22%2C%22First%20Login%22%3A%20%22FALSE%22%2C%22Platform%22%3A%20%22Web%22%7D; mp_85b4c2f8564a89844a5d5b0511f6c696_mixpanel=%7B%22distinct_id%22%3A%20%22app_EMP_MAIN_1%22%2C%22%24device_id%22%3A%20%2216feaef168263b-001a1921ec9369-39647b0e-fa000-16feaef168390b%22%2C%22%24initial_referrer%22%3A%20%22%24direct%22%2C%22%24initial_referring_domain%22%3A%20%22%24direct%22%2C%22%24user_id%22%3A%20%22app_EMP_MAIN_1%22%2C%22First%20Login%22%3A%20%22FALSE%22%2C%22Platform%22%3A%20%22Web%22%7D; mp_4299603418a0d9f0dc779424045ded30_mixpanel=%7B%22distinct_id%22%3A%20%22Megz_EMP1%22%2C%22%24device_id%22%3A%20%22170193287ed312-06bd1798514f12-1d346652-fa000-170193287ee92d%22%2C%22%24initial_referrer%22%3A%20%22%24direct%22%2C%22%24initial_referring_domain%22%3A%20%22%24direct%22%2C%22%24user_id%22%3A%20%22Megz_EMP1%22%2C%22First%20Login%22%3A%20%22FALSE%22%2C%22Platform%22%3A%20%22Web%22%7D; _ga_J0RTC60E5S=GS1.1.1581501157.13.0.1581501157.0
Host: localhost
Referer: http://localhost/home/
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.106 Safari/537
```

Request headers from React app:

```
{
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':"*",
      "Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
    }}
```

Comment: @KavithakaranKanapathippillai added request headers

Comment: @KavithakaranKanapathippillai added request headers from react app

Comment: you have to share the client code that makes the request, very probably the bug is there